# STM32F411CCU6 Blackpill - Progamming issue - The program isn't executed despite being loaded

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller

Bought new STM32F411CCU6 and ST-LINK V2 programmer. Connected ST-LINK to Blackpill  SWCLK->SWSCK, SWDIO->SWDIO. Then used STM32CubeIde to create a simple blinker project. Then created BIN file and it downloaded the Blackpill. Apparently(?), the programm was downloaded correctly, because the memory fields of the Blackpill are equal to the BIN file. (Or so I assume). However, nothing blinks: nor the onboard C13, nor externally connected LED on PA7. Pictures: [picture 1 Blinker code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhbdy.png) ; [picture 2 BIN file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXCU7.png) ; [picture 3 Device memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ikI.png) ; [picture 4 GPIO config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my6o9.png)

Comment: What is your clock configurations? It is possible that the clock configuration in cubemx does not match the board's crystal oscillator value. For simplicity you can set the clock source to internal clock (HSI) and try again.

Comment: Did you reset the device after programming? It is possible that the program was loaded, but remains in a halted state until reset.
It's also possible that the program fails before getting to the code that you've shared, so might be worth trying to run in debug.